# Is "height and width of knowledge" idiomatic?

Tags: idiomatic-language

"The height and width of knowledge determines the field of knowledge"

I am not sure if we say height and width to refer to two aspects that classify knowledge or any other similar concepts such as "experience" or "expertise".

Comment: We talk about the "depth and breadth" of someone's knowledge, but I've never heard "field of knowledge".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, but as Old Brixtonian pointed out, we use "depth" to refer to great expertise in a specific area, and "breadth" to refer to knowledge about many areas.